# How to connect a locally running Spring Boot application to AWS Elasticache Redis

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, spring-data-redis, amazon-elasticache

I have a Spring Boot Java application that's using spring-boot-starter-data-redis, and I have an AWS Elasticache Redis cache set up running in serverless mode in a dev environment. In my application.properties, I set the values for spring.redis.host and spring.redis.port. I saw the host and port value being set properly when starting up and the application can start up fine. But when I call an endpoint that uses the cache, it's throwing "Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Failed to connect to any host resolved for DNS name." I think this is because AWS Elasticache Redis cache can be accessed by applications in the same VPC only. How do I connect a locally running application to an AWS Elasticache Redis cache that's not running locally?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I connect a locally running application to an AWS Elasticache Redis cache that's not running locally?

You'll need to create an NLB in the same VPC as your Redis instance, and somehow secure external access to this NLB.

The easiest (but less secure) way is attaching a [security group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-security-groups.html) to the NLB and only allowing access from your IP. **Only do it if you have a static external IP address not shared with other computers you don't trust.** This rules out mobile providers and most home internet providers.

The alternative is setting up a [VPN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/).

AWS also supports authentication for Redis, however, most client libraries don't support it out of the box, so you would have make some [non-trivial changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77628889/aws-elasticache-for-redis-external-consumer-authentication-options/77629088#77629088) to your application code if you want to use it.

Keep in mind that typical Redis usage patterns are very sensitive to network latency. If you only use Redis for transient caching and don't need to share the cache with other machines, you might be better off setting up a local instance in a Docker container.